# How to embed Flash in IE 8 using SwfObject?

Tags: flash, debugging, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, swfobject

I tried SwfObject for loading swf on a website. It is all good with webkit and mozila based browsers but not with IE.

http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-productos.html

In IE 8 the footer not loading, it like crashes after the swf loads.
In IE 7 the player not working, so the footer loads.

How can I debug it? I have a Mac, Linux, Win7 with IE 8 64 bit. On IE 64-bit it gives a message to update the flash player but there is no update for this player from Adobe.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: could you add some code? does your `<object>` tag have an `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all get the latest swfobject js and expressinstall.swf file from here:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip&can=2&q=

I modified your code, it should work if you put the swfobject.js and expressinstall file where the html shows

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Resortes Hidalgo - Productos</title> 
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Resortes de compresión, resortes de tensión, resortes de torsión, anclas refractarias, troquelados, espirales, contrabalances, resortes de barra, muelles,resortes industriales, muelle, figuras de alambre, resorte,resortes mecanicos, tipos de resortes, Galvanizado, fabrica de resortes, hidalgo, rehisa, Resortes para Suspensión Automotriz, Resortes para Prensas Hidráulicas, criba, espirales de acero,resortes helicoidales, resortes progresivos, pernos, Galvanizado, Galvanizado Mecánico, Electropulido, Tropicalizado, Contrabalances, Carrocerias"> 
<meta name="description" content="Fabricamos resortes de tension, resortes de torsion, resortes de compresion, resortes de troquel, resortes de criba y mucho más. Visita nuestra página web y conoce nuestros productos. "> 
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="mewtg_KKkuA7WliXWmuFFS0UQaEjf_sarvK0p7L1Tyo" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="gsc.ventas.2010@gmail.com"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> 
<script src="Scripts/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20972071-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  function initMainFlash()
  {
    var fo = new Object();

    fo.flashvars = {};
    fo.params = {
        allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain"
    };
    fo.attributes = {
        id: "mainFlash",
        name: "mainFlash"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("productos.swf", "main_content", "675", "595", "10", "expressInstall.swf", fo.flashvars, fo.params, fo.attributes);
  }
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <!-- header --> 
        <div id="header"> 
            <div class="image"> 
                <img  width="930px" height="117px" alt="Resortes de Hidalgo s.a de c.v" title="Resortes de Hidalgo s.a de c.v" src="images/header_img.jpg" /> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
        <!-- /header --> 
        <!-- navigation --> 
        <div id="navigation"> 
            <ul> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/" ><img width="96px" height="96px" src="images/link_inicio.jpg" alt="Inicio" title="Inicio" /></a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <img width="96px" height="96px" src="images/box_1.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <img width="96px" height="96px" src="images/box_2.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <img width="96px" height="96px" src="images/box_3.jpg" alt="" title="" /> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-quien-somos.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_nuestra_empresa.jpg" alt="Nuestra Impresa" title="Nuestra Impresa" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/servicio-de-maquila-de-enrollado.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_servicio.jpg" alt="Servido de maquila de enrrollado hasta 14 mm. (.555) en CNC" title="Servido de maquila de enrrollado hasta 14 mm. (.555) en CNC" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/sistema-de-gestion-de-calidad-certificado.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_sistema.jpg" alt="Sistema de Calidad" title="Sistema de Calidad" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="resortes-hidalgo-productos.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_productos.jpg" alt="Productos" title="Productos" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-desarrollo-de-prototipos.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_ingenieria.jpg" alt="Ingenieria y Servicios" title="Ingenieria y Servicios" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-videos.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_videos.jpg" alt="Videos" title="Videos" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-imagenes.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_imagenes.jpg" alt="Imagenes" title="Imagenes" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
                <li> 
                    <a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-contacto.html"> 
                        <img src="images/link_contacto.jpg" alt="Contacto" title="Contacto" width="96px" height="96px" /> 
                    </a> 
                </li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> 
        <!-- /navigation --> 
        <!-- main content --> 
        <div id="main_content"> 
            SWFObject will replace the contents of this div with the Flash Movie.   
        </div> 
        <!-- /main content --> 
        <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div> 
        <div id="footer" class="page"> 
            <p>En Resortes Hidalgo, S.A. ofrecemos los siguientes productos: Resortes de compresión, resortes de tensión y  de torsión, anclas refractarias, troquelados, espirales, contrabalances, resortes de barra, muelles,  figuras de alambre, Galvanizado, resortes para Suspensión Automotriz,  espirales de acero, resortes helicoidales, resortes progresivos y más.</p> 
            <p><a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/">resortes</a> 
<a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-productos.html">productos</a> 
<a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-quien-somos.html">quien somos</a> 
<a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/servicio-de-maquila-de-enrollado.html">servicio de maquila de enrollado</a> 
<a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/sistema-de-gestion-de-calidad-certificado.html">sistema de gestion de calidad</a> 
<a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-desarrollo-de-prototipos.html">desarrollo de prototipos</a> 
<a href="resortes-hidalgo-videos.html">videos</a> 
<a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-imagenes.html">imagenes</a> 
<a href="http://www.rehisaresortes.com/resortes-hidalgo-contacto.html">contacto</a></p> 
            <p>www.rehisaresortes.com &copy; Design by GSS Global | <a title="seo simple" href="http://www.seo-simple.com.mx">seo simple</a></p> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <!-- container --> 
  <!-- scripts --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    initMainFlash();
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Good luck, Rob

Comment: No worries, it was a pleasure :D

Comment: I tried editing this answer to fix the missing closing quotes after the "mainFlash name, but it didn't allow me to edit less than 6 chars. Please fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Doron, I fixed it.